# Image copied in ROI doesn't follow camera c++. How to fix this?

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, rectangles, roi

I work on Windows7 x64 with opencv and Visual Studio 2010 on c++ language.

I created a project in which I show to my camera a rectangular area (call ***squared_surface***). This area is recognized by tracing a rectangle with `findSquare ()` and `drawSquares ()` of opencv file `squares.cpp`.
On this rectangle I create a ROI and there I copy an image (let's call ***copied_image)***

My problem is that when I rotate ***squared_surface*** (in front of camera), ***copied_image*** does not follow it.

I think I need to use the functions `getPerpective ()` and  `warpPerspective ()`, but I do not know how. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code:

```
int main(){
 vector<vector<Point> > squares;

 cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
 for (;;) {
    cv::Mat image;
    cap >> image;
    findSquares(image, squares);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++) {
    Rect rectangle = boundingRect(Mat(squares[i]));
                
    if((rectangle.width<=630)&& (rectangle.width >= 420) && (rectangle.height<= 490) &&(rectangle.height >= 250 )) {
        cv::Size dsize = Size(rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        Mat img1 = imread("scacchiera.jpg");
    cv::resize(img1,img1,dsize,0,0, INTER_LINEAR);
        Rect roi (rectangle.x, rectangle.y,rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        
    Mat imageRoi(image, roi);
       img1.copyTo(imageRoi);
       }
    } 
  drawSquares(image, squares);
  imshow("camera",image);
  if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT.**
I was thinking of rotating **Copied_image**, so it follows **Squared_surface**, but I need to calculate the angle of rotation of the rectangle identified by the camera (drawn in red in the above images). Is there a way to calculate this angle?

Or how can I do so that **Copied_image** follows **Squared_surface** when I rotate squared_surface?

Help me, please!

Comment: A Region of Interest is generally a left, right, top and bottom image co-ordinate -- not a rotated or skewed rectangle.  I don't know OpenCV, but you should be able to just take the corners you detected and create a textured rectangle.

Comment: How can I create a textured rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the bug. `Rect rectangle = boundingRect(Mat(squares[i]));` This is where the problem is. You are creating the variable `rectangle` as a bounding rectangle of the coordinates in `squares[i]`. So your code always tries to find out the bounding rectangle and not the actual rectangle.

Instead of using a bounding rectangle, try using a rotated rectangle. Here is how to use it: http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_rotated_rect.html

The rotated rectangle `RotatedRect (const Point2f &_center, const Size2f &_size, float _angle)` requires the center point location, floating point angle and the size. Since you have all the coordinates I think you can use basic math and trigonometry to calculate the center and the angle on how your rectangle should be rotated/orientated. 
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Just to make things clear, these are few examples of bounding rectangles: http://www.austincc.edu/cchrist1/GAME1343/TransformedCollision/BoundingRectangles.png , http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/10277/D15PX16.jpg ... you are looking for the actual rectangle. Otherwise your code works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks! I thought I could use RotatedRect, but I don't know how to calculate the angle. Any suggestions?

Comment: From trigonometry, for any line between 2 points A and B whose coordinates are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) respectively, angle of that line from the horizontal,  is atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)); you can use this link as a reference for atan http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan/

Comment: In your case, the angle for the rotatedrect will be the angle between line joining the bottom 2 points (or the top 2 points) and the horizontal. I believe you have all the points' coordinates in the squares[i] vector.